# My website shows 301 redirect error when trying to index?

Tags: wordpress

I requested indexing from the Google search console for my website https://ibowaterengineeringsolutions.com but it shows it can't index because I have a 301 redirect error.

[image]

I tried indexing again, but it still shows I have the error. please assist.